# How can I get Apache Solr to match documents that only contain some of the search terms?

Tags: solr

I am trying to implement Solr search in my php project. I have one text field

```
<field name="title" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

Example data

```
Foo Bar
```

When I try to search by `Foo` or `Foo Bar` it works well. But if I try to search by `Hello Foo` or `Hello Bar` it is not working.

How can I implement this type search using Solr?

Comment: How do you search? (May be with a code example)

Comment: Using Rest Api `solr/select/?q=Hello%20Foo&indent=on&wt=json&defType=edismax&qf=title&fl=id,title`

Answer (score 2):

The behavior depends on what the default operator in the schema is set to. If it's set to `AND`, both terms will have to match. Look for something similar to `<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND" />` to find out what you've currently set it to.

You can override the setting from `schema.xml` either by using `q.op=OR` in the query string, or by using the `mm` parameter (minimum must match (100% => AND, 0% => OR), which allows you to say "at least 75% of the terms must be present in the field).